# Prevent expect script from looking for a variable

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following function. It tests for a SFTP server connection. It does what it's supposed to, but it has one edge-case that's causing me a headache. When the variable SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD contains a dollar-sign it won't work because the expect script thinks it has to search for a variable.

```
function test_sftp_connection() {
expect << EOF
log_user 1
spawn -noecho sftp -P $SFTP_SERVER_PORTNUMBER $SFTP_SERVER_USERNAME@$SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME
expect "password:"
send "$SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD\r"
expect {
    "sftp>" {
      send "exit\r"
      expect eof
      exit 0
    }
    timeout {
      exit 1
    }
  }
EOF
}
```

I tried various solutions:

1. `send $SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD"\r"`
2. `send "$SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD\r"`
3. `send "'$SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD'\r"`

But they all end up with the same error:
`'can't read "[few letters after dollar-sign in password]": no such variable'.`

I guess this is hard because it is using a Bash variable in an expect script. But I still think this should be solvable. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I suggest public key authentication or install sshpass.

Comment: This is not my SFTP-server, so I can't make the call on what authentication options they give me. I didn't know such a thing like sshpass existed; it seems nice. Do you think it would work in the given context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the viewpoint of the Tcl language:

You have to escape the `$` if you want to send a $ literally:

```
 send "\$your password\r"
```

However your case is complicated in that you pass to the Tcl program a string, which undergoes parameter expansion by the shell. This means that if you have a **shell variable** `SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD`, and the variable contains a `$`, there would be no escaping.

One solution would be to replace every `$` inside the shell variable by the string `\$`. However in my opinion, this is cumbersome and error prone. A similar possibility would be to place the shell variable into the environment, before calling Tcl, i.e.

```
export SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD
```

and then in your Tcl script do a

```
send \$env(SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD)\r
```

This also fixes the danger of code injection. In your original approach, a password containing inside the string `[foo]` , would try to execute the Tcl command `foo`, and if the string between the brackets happens to be a **valid** Tcl function, it could execute arbitrary Tcl code under the hood.

Note that the backslash in front of the `$env` has the purpose to tell the shell NOT to interpret `env` as shell variable. This is necessary because you have the complete Tcl program included in a double quoted context.

If you find this escaping ugly (as I would), you can ask the shell to completely keep its fingers from the Tcl text. Right now, you are "using" the shell to expand the variables in the `spawn` command. This is fine, since these variables won't contain a white space or a character which is special to Tcl, but still I would decouple here Tcl and shell completely:

If you place those variables into the environment as well and refer to then via `$env(....)` inside Tcl, you can put your whole Tcl program into single quoted context (or perhaps into its own file, with a `#!/usr/bin/expect` line on top and don't have to worry about shell issues anymore.

Comment: Would have been wonderful if it worked. Unfortunately; this results in the same error.

Comment: I tried again because I noticed I still had single quotations in between the double quotations from a previous test. After changing that so it matches your example exactly; the error was different: it can't find the variable now.

Comment: @MaestroMaus : Ah, I misunderstood your question. I think I now know what you mean, and adjusted my answer.

Comment: @MaestroMaus : Maybe you have a typo when exporting the variable. Update your question to show the exact code you are using now.

Comment: @MaestroMaus : I forgot to send the carriage return. Fixed my example.

Comment: @MaestroMaus : Ah, wait. there is one more problem. I'll fix it.

Comment: @MaestroMaus : Should be OK now.

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct answer yet; but regardless of that, it's a quality answer now just because of the sheer amount of explanation going on. I learned from it just reading it; thanks for that! I will try your solution tomorrow.

Comment: Great; it works! Accepted the answer; thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should prevent the double-evaluation effect you're seeing:

```bash
function test_sftp_connection() {
    export SFTP_SERVER_PORTNUMBER SFTP_SERVER_USERNAME SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME
    expect << 'END_EXPECT'
        log_user 1
        spawn -noecho sftp -P $env(SFTP_SERVER_PORTNUMBER) $env(SFTP_SERVER_USERNAME)@$env(SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME)
        expect "password:"
        send "$env(SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD)\r"
        expect {
            timeout { exit 1 }
            "sftp>" { send "exit\r" }
        }
        expect eof
        exit 0
END_EXPECT
}
```

- use a quoted heredoc. That keeps the shell from interpreting any of the variables inside the expect code
- pass shell variables to expect through the environment.